# rxjs: reset to streams and only get one out put

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have two separate streams that come together in a combineLatest in something like the following:

```
const programState$ = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    high$, low$,
    (high, low) => {
        return program(high, low);
    });
```

This works fine and dandy but I also want to be able to reset both the high$ and the low$ to their initial state and only fire the program once.  Those kind of look like the following:

```
const high$ = initialDataBranchOne$.merge(interactiveHigh$);
const low$ = initialDataBranchTwo$.merge(interactiveLow$);
```

Both of those come from an initialData stream that is fired fromEvent.  While the program runs normally the combineLatest works great. How can I achieve the same result when the initialData fromEvent is fired?  Right now the program gets run twice.

Comment: Can you clarify what the `initialDataBranch` and the `interactive` streams are? It's unclear what's working and what is not. When exactly does your program fail or have unexpected behavior and what is that behavior?

Comment: @CalvinBelden both initialDataBranch one and two both come from initialData stream that is fired from a fromEvent.  The program behaves as expected from combineLatest but not as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can store the `high` and `low` properties in the same object. We can then perform a `scan` as various events come in to update this state:

```
// Define your default high/low values
const defaultHighLow = /** **/;

// Different types of updates/actions
const highUpdate$ = high$.map(high => ({ high, type: 'UPDATE HIGH' }));
const lowUpdate$ = low$.map(low => ({ low, type: 'UPDATE LOW' }));
const resetUpdate$ = reset$.map(high => ({ type: 'RESET' }));

// Merge all the different types of actions to single stream
const update$ = Rx.Observable.merge(highUpdate$, lowUpdate$, resetUpdate$);

// Scan over these updates to modify the high/low values
const highLowState$ = update$.scan((state, update) => {
  if (update.type === 'UPDATE HIGH') {
    return { ...state, high: update.high };
  }

  if (update.type === 'UPDATE LOW') {
    return { ...state, low: update.low };
  }

  // Return defaultHighLow if reset update is triggered
  if (update.type === 'RESET') {
    return defaultHighLow;
  }

  // Return state by default
  return state;
}, defaultHighLow).startWith(defaultHighLow);
```

And finally we can derive the program state as before:

```
const programState$ = highLowState$.map(hl => program(hl.high, hl.low));
```

Comment: Let me understand you a little better, so defaultHighLow will be the state and my resetUpdate, highUpdate, lowUpdate will just update the values of defaultHighLow via scan?

Comment: `defaultHighLow` will contain your app's default values for `high` and `low`. Whenever a reset update occurs, we return those default values. Otherwise, we either update the `high` value or the `low` value. Does that make sense?